# Duplicates in Sum SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sum, duplicates

The code I have works great except for it sums the deposit amount for multiple dates instead of only the corresponding date and account. For example:

Account #: 123 / Date: 01/01/2012 / Deposit Required: $100 / Deposit: $100

Account #: 123 / Date: 01/20/2012 / Deposit Required: $100 / Deposit: $100

**Query Results:**

Account #: 123 / Date: 01/01/2012 / Deposit Required: $100 / Deposit: $200

Account #: 123 / Date: 01/20/2012 / Deposit Required: $100 / Deposit: $200

It is the same persons account but with two different dates. The deposit amount should only sum the amount corresponding to the account # & date. Thanks for any help!

```
SELECT ca.fdorgunit AS Facility
, pt.fdmedrecnum AS Account
, ca.fddos AS DOS
, Cast(iv.fdinnetdeposit/100.0 as decimal(10,2)) AS [Deposit Required]
, Sum(Case When pa.fddescription = 'Deposit' Then Cast(pa.fdpayadjamount/100.0 as decimal(10,2)) Else 0 END) AS Deposit
FROM OPENQUERY (VISION, 'SELECT * FROM de.tbinsverification') AS iv
LEFT JOIN OPENQUERY (VISION, 'SELECT * FROM ci.tbcase') AS ca
ON iv.fdcase = ca.id
JOIN OPENQUERY (VISION, 'SELECT * FROM de.tbpatient') AS pt
ON pt.id = ca.fdpatient
LEFT JOIN OPENQUERY (VISION, 'SELECT * FROM ar.tbpayadjmaster') AS pa
ON pa.fdpatient = pt.id
WHERE iv.fdinnetdeposit is not Null AND iv.fdinnetdeposit <> '0' AND ca.fdcasestatus = 'Performed'
GROUP BY ca.fdorgunit, ca.fddos, iv.fdinnetdeposit, pt.fdmedrecnum
```

Below is how it should look in the table but the current query is returning a Deposit of $200 for both 10/10/16 & 10/20/16 dates:

```
Facility | Account |  DOS     | Deposit Required | Deposit
1        |   1234  | 10/10/16 |    $100          |  $100
1        |   1234  | 10/20/16 |    $100          |  $100
```

Comment: what is: `ca.fdoirunit` `ca.fddos` `iv.fdinnetdeposit` and `pt.fdmedrecnum`?  because you're grouping by these fields, not only account and date.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the sum of **Deposit Required** and **Deposit** by Month and Year, in your GROUP BY, try this.

```
GROUP BY ca.fdorgunit, MONTH(ca.fddos), YEAR(ca.fddos), iv.fdinnetdeposit, pt.fdmedrecnum
```

Comment: I wanted it grouped as is but not have the deposit amount doubled when the person has made a deposit on multiple dates. The query is just recognizing the deposit made but not that date resulting in the double amount.

Comment: @Tosh Did you mean that one of the records should not have a Deposit Amount value?

Comment: No, The same account has two different dates of a deposit. The query is summing all the deposits made for the account and putting the total of all on each date. I need the total for only the deposits that were made for the particular date. See the query results I posted above. The deposit amount for both dates should be only $100 but it is returning $200 for both dates.

Comment: Could you post the data that should be computed. The values in the tables? I can't visualize it with your given data.

Comment: @jelliase - I have added how the table should look in the original post above. Thanks!